# GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT not the same as glFlush?

Tags: opengl

I've seen in several places the claim that calling `glClientWaitSync` with `GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT` is equivalent to calling `glFlush` after generating a fence. I tried it with my code but it seemed not to work as expected.

My code generates a vector of PBO/fence pairs, and passes them on. Later, a loop waits on the fences and then uses the associated PBO. On my system, `glClientWaitSync`(fence, 0, 0) worked fine. On a coleague's, and when using a dual screen setup, it blocked forever. The problem was solved by doing a `glFlush` after creating the fence.

Since I have read in some places that `GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT` is potentially faster, I tried replacing the flush with that. The result was that the blocking behaviour returned.

What could be the reason for the difference? Any idea how to identify it?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating the fence in a different OpenGL context?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Everything happens in the same context. I eventually just added the glFlush(), in a better place.